# How to access the Desktop Composition Engine from a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-vista

Is it possible to access the Desktop Composition Engine in Windows Vista from a winforms application?  The DCE apparently involves applications rendering to DCE buffers instead of directly to the screen.  Since a winforms app has no way of getting information about the monitor's refresh rate and scanline status (other than via DirectX), animation in a winforms app is subject to tearing effects.  With DCE enabled, the tearing effects are lessened but still there (apparently the DCE can still grab a buffer that your app is halfway through writing to and render it to the screen, thereby producing the half-one-frame-half-of-the-next tearing effects).

Is there any way for my winforms app to communicate with the DCE and possible avoid rendering during buffer switchover times?

Answer (score 1):

Could you import the DWMAPI.DLL, call [DwmGetCompositionTimingInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969514%28VS.85%29.aspx), tear apart the [DWM_TIMING_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969503%28VS.85%29.aspx) struct and synch your app with whatever timing information you can discern?

Alternatively, you might be able to control it with [DwmSetDxFrameDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969522%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Have you ever encountered any C# samples that wrap this?

Comment: I have not.  But this blog looks promising to either have examples or to have links to examples - http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/tags/DWM/default.aspx